# Is it possible to replace org.apache.axis2.wso2 artifacts with org.apache.axis2 artifacts?

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, axiom, wso2-as

folks!

I need to update artifacts in a project that is running on wso2 server.
There were used wso2 specific artifacts like org.apache.axis2.wso2 or org.apache.ws.commons.axiom.wso2.

If I want to replace these wso2 specific artifacts with more up-to-date regular org.apache.axis2 artifacts could it lead to errors or I can use non specific artifacts freely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 creates its own versions of such 3rd party libraries in 2 cases.

1. When the original jar is not OSGi
2. When WSO2 needs to add new fixes and improvement which are not
   there is the original jar

In either case, changing a jar to its original version can break the server.

On the other hand, new versions of those 3rd party jars can have API (signature) changes too. So it can also break the server.

So the bottom line is it won't be possible to do such jar upgrades without internal code changes.

Comment: Thank you, Bee, I think in the same direction, bu wanted to consult about this issue.